# Are $S^2$ and $S^3$ homotopy equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Are $S^2$ and $S^3$ homotopy equivalent, are they homeomorphic? How would one show this? They have the same fundamental group. I know $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 $ are not homotopy equivalent. I can't think of how to show any of this.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$ are both contractible spaces so homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a partial answer.

It's easy to see they are not homeomorphic if you know $\Bbb{R}^3$ and $\Bbb{R}$ aren't, since if you remove a point from $S^n$ you get $\Bbb{R}^n$. (So, if you have a homeomorphism between $S^2$ and $S^3$, by removing a point from each one, you would get a homeomorphism between $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}^3$).

One way to to show they are not homotopy equivalent would be to actually compute their higher homotopy groups, which is perhaps a little more complicated than computing the homotopy groups of $\Bbb{R}^n$ minus a point (which is how you show $\Bbb{R}^3$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ aren't homeomorphic). But I think this should appear in many textbooks on the subject.

A simpler way would be to compute their homology groups, which is much easier. This should definitely appear in any textbook on the subject, and I think I won't do a better job giving a crash course on that here. Perhaps someone else will.

Answer (score 1):

Closed manifolds of different dimensions are never homotopy equivalent. Actually, the dimension of a closed manifold $M$ is an invariant (under homotopy equivalence) that you can read off by looking for the largest $n$ such that $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is nontrivial. Here $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is the $n$-th homology of the manifold $M$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficient, which is a homotopy invariant.

If you stick with orientable manifolds, then you can use $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient instead.